# Ubuntu 15.10. Installed php but browser download pages instead of open

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

I'm installing LAMP on UBUNTU and I followed [this guide](https://www.atlantic.net/community/howto/install-lamp-ubuntu-15-10-linux-apache-mysql-php/) but in the final step, when I write the info.php page and try to open it, by browser downloads it instead of open.
I googled the problem but I found no solution.
Do you have any?

EDIT: I actually solved the problem installing

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

The problem is that now, although I restart apache, I can never see the page. Is alway 404 not found.

Comment: Are you sure you've installed apache php module?

Comment: I did this sudo apt-get install php5, as the guide says.
I don't know if is there anything else I'm missing

Comment: Did you added the `LoadModule php5_module "modules/libphp5.so"` and 
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php` lines to your apache config?

Comment: @lolka_bolka shouldn't this be done using 'a2enmod' ?

Comment: How are you trying to access the page? Are you going to http://127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: I'm both using 127.0.0.1 and localhost

Answer (score 2):

it means that your server doesn't have PHP or the Apache PHP module installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

and if you have installed then, do you have your index.php located in `/var/www/`?

Make sure to enable PHP with the command

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

**Case :2**

you are accessing the PHP file as a file on c drive (eg. `C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php` or `file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/index.php`) instead of as a webpage (ie `//localhost/index.php`).

**Case :3**

The mcrypt module is not enabled by default. Enable the mcrypt module and then restart apache.

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Case : 4**

Check port that you are use its generally 8080 and mysql is run on 443 port.In case you are use port file path like:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.php
```

In some cases port need to change in skype use 80 so you replace port from tool->option->advance make it differ port.

Comment: About libapache2-mod-php5 it's already installed; and if I sudo a2enmod php5 it "says" Module php5 already enabled.
If I restart apache2 it asks me for the password but I still see Error 404

Comment: If your using Firefox, you may have to clear your cache as well.

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: can you check file is installed or not in /etc/apache2 and the file libphp5

Comment: Into /etc/apache2 there is apache2.conf (is the one you were asking for?)... libphp5 where is supposed to be?

Comment: a2query -m php5 runthis

Comment: php5 (enabled by maintainer script)

Comment: okay, may be mcrypt is not enabled here,
`sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: No, it still asks me for the download

Comment: can you please send your path of file i mean what you are run in url

Comment: /etc/php5/apache/conf.d folder have you mcrypt.ini

Comment: which browser are you use?

Comment: into /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ I do have this 20-mcrypt.ini. Is it the same?

Comment: I DID IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! (Sorry for all the !'s but I'm excited!) It was a problem dued by the port. I changed the port into 8080 and now it works

Comment: I am just posting for this.If you are use a skype you port is reserved

Comment: If you get an answer then mark question as a answered

Comment: Yes, actually I don't have skype because I just reinstalled ubuntu and those are the first things I'm installing on it. For this reason it seemed weird to me.
But anyways, now it works. Lesson learned.
Thaks for your help